# Is this a model for $K$-theory of a triangulated category?

Tags: reference-request, kt.k-theory-and-homology, simplicial-stuff, algebraic-k-theory, triangulated-categories

The recent question [Complete the following sequence: point, triangle, octahedron, . . . in a dg-category](https://mathoverflow.net/q/236489/41291) reminded me of something I wanted to clarify long time ago; most likely this is now well known but unfortunately I did not follow literature in the field attentively enough.

As pointed out in [one of the answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/236621/41291) to that question (by [Piotr Achinger](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3847/piotr-achinger)), it is all about Exercise IV.2 1(c) (p. 260) in Gelfand & Manin's "Methods of Homological Algebra".

Shortly, any composable $n$-tuple of morphisms in a triangulated category $\mathscr T$ gives a bunch of distinguished triangles which can be organized into a $\it hypersimplex$ - polytope modelled by the convex hull of edge midpoints of a (regular) $(n+1)$-simplex $\Delta^{n+1}$.

Now it seems that one may use this to define certain simplicial set out of $\mathscr T$. For that, we view each such hypersimplex as some sort of a map of $\Delta^{n+1}$ to $\mathscr T$: we map all vertices to some new entity $*$, edges to objects of $\mathscr T$ corresponding to vertices of this hypersimplex, etc. Then the standard cosimplicial space structure on $\Delta^*$ gives a simplicial structure on the collection of all hypersimplices as follows:

There is a unique 0-simplex $*$;

1-simplices are objects of $\mathscr T$, degeneracy of $*$ being the zero object;

2-simplices are distinguished triangles, and faces of ${\bf T}=(A\to B\to C\to\Sigma A)$ are

$d_0({\bf T})=A$, $d_1({\bf T})=B$, $d_2({\bf T})=C$;

moreover degeneracies of an object $X$ are

$s_0(X)=(X=X\to0\to\Sigma X)$ and $s_1(X)=(0\to X=X\to\Sigma0)$.

3-simplices are octahedra, faces being those four faces of the octahedron which are distinguished triangles.

I've posted an image of a 4-simplex to the page of the above question. This is something Wikipedia calls [rectified 5-cell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectified_5-cell), it's like this:

[image]

Its faces are the five octahedra that can be seen in the picture - four ones adjacent (from inside) to the facets of the outer tetrahedron and the central one.

I guess everybody reading about triangulated categories for the first time and having seen simplicial identities before (or vice versa) comes up with this immediately; the point here is just that because of the above description of hypersimplices it is more or less clear that one indeed obtains a simplicial set (well, when $\mathscr T$ is small at any rate).

My questions are:

> Does this simplicial set give a model for the $K$-theory of $\mathscr T$? Seems like its fundamental group is $K_0(\mathscr T)$...
>
> Is this a Kan complex? Triangle axioms and the octahedron axiom seem to translate into something about the Kan conditions, does this extend up?
>
> There seems to be more structure produced by the shift functor; is this actually a [cyclic set](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cyclic+set)? Can this structure be extended to a [$\Gamma$-space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Gamma-space), or turned into an [E$_\infty$-space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/E-infinity+space) using any other machinery?
>
> Is all this done accurately somewhere?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this was a Kan complex since (as I mentioned in the other post) it's not known whether every triangulated category is n-angulated for all n. (For example, this would imply that every *pre-triangulated* category is automatically triangulated, i.e. that the octahedral axiom is redundant. That would surprise most people, I think.)

Comment: @DylanWilson So is n-angulated the same as this thing being a Kan complex?

Comment: @DylanWilson Sorry for bringing this up again, but re-contemplating it occurred to me that I don't actually understand your comment. If we start with a pre-triangulated category then I don't see how to obtain the Kan condition on the third level that would be furnished by the octahedron axiom.